# Batch ListFile.txt creation problems

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am very new to batch file programing I have found and modified this script

```
dir /b C:\mydocuments*.* > C:\Test\Listfile.txt
```

It is supposed to search in a dir and make a list of all the files in that dir but nothing happens there is just a flash of cmd I am using windows 7 X64 bit. thanks for your help

Comment: Open this batch script in a command prompt window rather than just double-clicking it to see any error messages; I guess you miss a backslash immediately before `*.*`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you check out [THIS](http://ss64.com/nt/) website its really good also in future you can do a little more troubleshooting research by checking out [THIS](http://www.dostips.com/) website.

These are your problems.

1. Your wildcard ( `*.*` ) does not have a `\` in front of it.
2. Your `path` needs to be `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents` where username is your computers name.
3. Also you have to `MKDIR` first... or get around it.

here is the fixed code it works on my Windows 10 PC

```
@ECHO OFF
IF not exist "C:\Test\" MKDIR C:\Test\
DIR /B C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\*.* > C:\Test\Listfile.txt
PAUSE
```

Remember to use @ECHO OFF at the beginning of a batch file.

Comment: actually @echo on will help you as you will be able to see whats happening

Comment: Thank you Jonas I'll check them out. your code is very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

path is not correct.
it should be `c:\mydocuments\*.*`